# If $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is equipped with $\|\cdot\|_1$, then $\delta f =f(0)$ is an unbounded operator.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that if you equip $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ with the one-norm $\|f\|_1=\intop_{0}^{1}\left|f(x)\right|\mathrm{d}x$, then the operator

$$\delta:\mathcal{C}([0,1])\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$\delta: f(x)\mapsto f(0)$$

is an unbounded operator.  Would it be easier to show directly that there doesn't exist a constant $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\left|f(0)\right|\le C\intop_{0}^{1}\left|f(x)\right|\mathrm{d}x\qquad\forall f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])$$

or to show that $\ker \delta$ is open?

Comment: Show nonexistence of $C$.  Do not show the kernel is open.

Comment: Directly. Consider a set of function that are $1$ in $0$, $0$ on $[1/n,1]$ and linear between $0$ and $1/n$. The kernel is not open, by the way.

Comment: Note that "not closed" is not the same as "open".

Comment: @MartinArgerami, a momentary lapse in reasoning hehe.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Given any $n>0$, can you construct $f\in L^1$ with $\|f\|_1 = 1$ and $f(0)=n$?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Also my undergrad differential geometry course at UCSD relied heavily on your notes, I'm indebted.

Comment: Very cool, @MobiusDickus. I'm actually in SD now :) ... Welcome to MSE ... Please don't forget to accept answers once you're satisfied (so that the questions don't stay on the unanswered list); if you're not satisfied, of course, ask more ... :)

Comment: I will accept yours as soon as MSE allows me (there is a timer for us newbies).

Comment: Cool :) Cute name, BTW. Shouldn't you have Möbius, however? :D ... Hope you come back to more geometry down the road :) Were you in Jeff Rabin's class?

Comment: Point taken, I've fixed it haha. And yes, Jeff Rabin's!  Your notes were essentially a required text.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical proof is as indicated by Ted and Peter. Here's another way.

Given $f\in C[0,1]$, let $f_n=f\,1_{[1/n,1]}$. Then $\delta f_n=0$, and $$\|f-f_n\|_1\leq\frac{\|f\|_1}{n},$$so $f_n\to f$. This shows that $\ker\delta$ is dense.